# Enable "not thread-safe" warning for Swing Controls in MATLAB

Tags: java, swing, matlab, user-interface, event-dispatch-thread

By default Swing *"not thread-safe"* warnings are disabled in MATLAB. Does anyone know what is the **identifier** of this warning so that I could enable it in MATLAB?

[Yair Altman](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/author/88835) posted about it years ago but I am not able find it any more. See also http://www.mathworks.ch/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/129919

This link is about thread safety and **WHY IT IS IMPORTANT**: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-and-the-event-dispatch-thread-edt/

Comment: why do you want to enable them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try one or more of the following:

```
com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop.getInstance.enableThreadSafeGetMethods()
com.mathworks.mwswing.MJUtilities.setThreadingChecksEnabled(true)
com.mathworks.mwswing.MJUtilities.setThreadSafetyWarningStackTraceSuppressed(false)
```

Yair